# Why do I get this output when doing a pip install uwsgi: error linking uWSGI

Tags: python, anaconda, uwsgi

When I do this:

```
python -m pip install 'uwsgi==2.0.*'
```

I get:

```
gcc: error: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a: No such file or directory
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-92sgnbd8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include/python3.9/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.
```

If it helps, the full output was:

```
python -m pip install 'uwsgi==2.0.*'
Collecting uwsgi==2.0.*
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 804 kB 439 kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-sceja6o0
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/
  Complete output (157 lines):
  /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 8
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include/libxml2 -I/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***

  *** uWSGI linking ***
  gcc -pthread -B /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/compiler_compat -o build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o lib/linux_ns.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -ldl -lz -lpcre -luuid -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -lxml2 -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -lz -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -llzma -lpthread -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -liconv -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -ldl -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm -lm /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a -lutil -lcrypt
  gcc: error: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a: No such file or directory
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
    Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-92sgnbd8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include/python3.9/uwsgi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/
    Complete output (150 lines):
    /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 8
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include/libxml2 -I/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    ... etc
    core/yaml.o is up to date
    core/xmlconf.o is up to date
    [thread 3][gcc -pthread -B /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/compiler_compat] core/dot_h.o
    [thread 2][gcc -pthread -B /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/compiler_compat] core/config_py.o
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    plugins/python/python_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyutils.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyloader.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/gil.o is up to date
    plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o is up to date
    plugins/python/profiler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/symimporter.o is up to date
    plugins/python/tracebacker.o is up to date
    plugins/python/raw.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/gevent.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/hooks.o is up to date
    plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cache/cache.o is up to date
    plugins/nagios/nagios.o is up to date
    plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o is up to date
    plugins/carbon/carbon.o is up to date
    plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o is up to date
    plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/http/http.o is up to date
    plugins/http/keepalive.o is up to date
    plugins/http/https.o is up to date
    plugins/http/spdy3.o is up to date
    plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o is up to date
    plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o is up to date
    plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o is up to date
    plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o is up to date
    plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o is up to date
    plugins/router_http/router_http.o is up to date
    plugins/logfile/logfile.o is up to date
    plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o is up to date
    plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/router_static/router_static.o is up to date
    plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o is up to date
    plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o is up to date
    plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o is up to date
    plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o is up to date
    plugins/router_expires/expires.o is up to date
    plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_template/tt.o is up to date
    plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
    *** uWSGI linking ***
    gcc -pthread -B /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/compiler_compat -o /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o lib/linux_ns.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/ugreen/ugreen.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -rdynamic -ldl -lz -lpcre -luuid -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -lxml2 -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -lz -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -llzma -lpthread -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -liconv -L/home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -ldl -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm -lm /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a -lutil -lcrypt
    gcc: error: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.a: No such file or directory
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xx9rwmdr/uwsgi_881aca9c10424110862a3558e3738db5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-92sgnbd8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/snowcrash/mambaforge/include/python3.9/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: you might just be missing the python development headers; the package is called `python3-dev` under Ubuntu, but varies under other distros and may be something special because of your anaconda(?) env .. otherwise you may simply be missing `gcc` (`build-essentials` should get everything under Ubuntu)

Comment: On Centos 7 it was `sudo yum install python3-devel`