# Why do I get /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Tags: python, pip

When I do `python -m pip install 'uwsgi==2.0.*'`

I'm getting:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

`which pip` gives:

```
/home/snowcrash/.local/bin/pip
```

If I do `pip` I get:

```
pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/snowcrash/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal.cli.main
```

This does not seem to help [/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023599/usr-local-bin-python-no-module-named-pip)

Comment: have you installed `python-pip` for the same python you run?

Comment: It seems like you had it [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69725792/3001761) - what have you changed since? When you say _"does not seem to help"_, could you provide some more detail?

Comment: I have no idea. 1. Why would I have different versions of python? and 2. how would you install `python-pip` for a specific version? and 3. why is it called `python-pip` instead of `pip`? and 4. is there a difference between `python-pip` and `pip`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have no idea. Question 5. Why was it working yesterday but not today?

Comment: did you by any chance run `pip install --upgrade pip` in your virtual environmet? Btw in linux (depending on the distro) there is installed python2. Try installing `python3-pip`

Comment: 1. Linux used to ship with both python2 and python3 for compatibility reasons. You said you're on Ubuntu 20 and I think they finally got rid of python2 there (as it's been out-of-life already when that ubuntu released) 2. In the linked question, comments tell you to also install (sudo apt install) python3-dev - start with it, maybe it will fix whatever broke.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your *exact* situation, but this suggestions can be helpful:

### To fix the `No module named pip._internal.cli.main` error

It seems like you have a broken `pip`. I mean, incomplete (and incompatible) parts of pip living in the same Python distribution, that generates... a useless pip. That's why you hit with those weird errors.

Something you can do is re-installing pip (from scratch). Consider tools like `get-pip.py` or `python -m ensurepip`. See the reference of this problem at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599).

### To fix the error with `python -m pip`

Also, you may have Python 2 installed in addition of Python 3. To verify that, run `python --version`. If you get a Python 2 version, try `python3 --version`. If you don't get errors (and receive a Python 3 version), replace `python -m pip` with `python3 -m pip`. That should fix your `No module named pip` issue. Also, you can run `python3 -m ensurepip` (or `python -m ensurepip`, if `python3` doesn't exist).

However, if that doesn't work, maybe you will have to re-install the whole Python.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on Ubuntu when I don't use virtual environment,
I tried to upgrade pip with this command but it didn't work.

```bash
/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

So I used this command and issue is fixed.

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

If you don't use Ubuntu Python 3, you can use;

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be issue in venv, however when I deactivate venv and uninstall pip3.
With reinstall python3-pip it seems to work in main environment, but still not in venv.